# Detect and get dialled number in Android using Appcelerator

Tags: appcelerator, titanium-modules, appcelerator-titanium

I am looking for a way to detect if the user is dialling a number that is 'like' a value in my database. I have got a REST api working to retrieve numbers for my application, just need a way to intercept and compare for Android in Appcelerator.

I have looked around but can't find a way to do this within Appcelerator, not sure where to start. I looked on a forum (https://archive.appcelerator.com/question/117852/detecting-phone-call-on-android) but no results.

Would this be an Android service and check in the background if a user is dialling? (http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Android.Service) or is there a better way? Maybe I could use the Android intent functionality (http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Android_Intent_Filters-section-43287610_AndroidIntentFilters-RespondtotheCallingActivity) or better still maybe there is a module for this. Had a look on their site, could only see one but it's a paid module(https://marketplace.appcelerator.com/apps/5672?restoreSearch=true#!overview). Not even sure if it works though.

Any help or point in the right direction is appreciated.

Comment: You would have to write an external module to do that. I suggest you contact the seller of the modules you referenced to and ask exactly what it does, and when, and if it runs in the background. If you need something really customized to your needs you would have to write your own.

Comment: As @developer82 has mentioned, you need to create a custom android module for this action.